# LOTRO crashes in PlayOnLinux after Login (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I'm quite new to Linux and hence a bit helpless.

I tried to install LOTRO on my Lenovo Ideapad with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.
I followed a few different guides to get it done:

1. installing wine (seems to be successful)
2. installing PlayOnLinux (seems to be successful)
3. creating a wineprefix (version 1.9.20, 32bit)
4. choose the LOTRO installer
5. copy the installation folder to /PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/LOTRO/drive_c/Program Files/Turbine/The Lord of the Rings Online

After this the Launcher starts without any trouble and I'm able to login and choose a world.
Once the world is chosen, the game seems to start but **blacks out and hangs** :/

I have no ideas what I could do, as I don't even get any Error messages..
What is this problem based on?

(all previous threads I found are just concerning the Installation, but I already passed this stage)

Comment: Have you run the game from a terminal and looked for any relevant messages in the terminal window?

Comment: Like @OrganicMarble said, type "wine (your.exe)" and post any errors.